# Not updating the current location in MKMapView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I am using CLLocationManager to update the current location but some times the current location is lost. I don't know why the current location is losing.

Please help me out of this.

Thank you,
Madan Mohan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The location can become lost for a wide variety of reasons:

- The device no longer has reasonably open access to the sky so GPS satellite information is unavailable.
- There aren't enough cell towers available to perform triangulation.
- The wifi access point isn't in the database of known access points.
- The user switched to Airplane Mode.

And many more. Location-aware applications have to assume they'll lose geolocation information at any time. It often comes back moments later.

Answer (score 2):

If you didnt get any update on your location then this delegate might be called

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error 
{
switch([error code])
{
   case kCLErrorLocationUnknown: 
   //The location manager was unable to obtain a location value right now

   case kCLErrorDenied: 
   //Access to the location service was denied by the user

   case kCLErrorNetwork: 
   //The network was unavailable or a network error occurred.

   case kCLErrorHeadingFailure:
   // The heading could not be determined.
 }
```

You can find out whats the problem is.