# Current location is lost sometimes when using google API

Tags: objective-c, google-maps

I am using Location manager to find out where I am (Current location). But in some use cases I lose my current location. I don't  know what is happening on that time. If you guys any one is already experience with this problem ?. Can you please let me know if it only happening only for me ?. Or if you already face this problem share me the solution for this.

Thanks to all,
Monish.

Comment: Can you describe the use cases where this loss happens? Perhaps the device has not settled on the location as is the case immediately after resuming from sleep.

Comment: actually at first I am getting the current location and when I to another controller and came back some times the current location is lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several very good reasons why you'll lose location, and it's perfectly normal.

I answered this same question here yesterday. [Take a look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334565/not-updating-the-current-location-in-mkmapview/4335072#4335072).

Comment: @ mathew:thanks for ur response but I tried to print the error in my console in didFailWithError method.But the error printed in my console is like as:Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)"

Comment: Can you please tell me what it mean and how to resolve it or any suggestions.